# Find the limits of integration when changing a double integral to polar coordinates.

Tags: calculus, integration

$$\iint_{R}\sqrt{25-x^2-y^2}\ dA$$
$$r = { (x,y) | x^2 + y^2 ≤ 25, x ≥ 0 }$$

So far I know the limits in terms of $r$, but not in terms of $\theta$:
$$\iint_{0}^{5}r\sqrt{25-r^2}\,drdA$$

Comment: What is the region $R$ you are integrating over?

Comment: r = { (r,theta) | (x, y) | x^2 + y^2 ≤ 25, x ≥ 0 }

Comment: Your region $R$ is **right part** of the disc with the center in the origin and with the radius $5$. So, limits for $\theta$ are $\frac{-\pi}{2} \le \theta \le \frac{\pi}{2}$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $r$ is the disc centred at the pole with radius $5,$ then $\theta$ completes a circuit, so you may let it range from $0$ to $2π.$

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your region of integration. If it's the full disc centered at the origin, then integrate from $0$ to $2\pi$. Otherwise, you need to check where it begins and ends; for instance, a semicircle region might require you to integrate from $0$ to $\pi$. Since it seems like you're finding the volume of a cone, though, it's most likely the full disc.

Comment: To @Stephen Goree : Region $R$ is given in the comment to original question...

Comment: @AntonVrdoljak Ah I see now. Thanks.

Edit: OP said "r" and not "R," and that's what threw me off.

Answer (score 0):

The integration region is the half-circle on the right, with the angular limits $\theta \in (-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2)$. Then, polar integral is

$$\int_{-\frac\pi2}^{\frac\pi2} \int_{0}^{5}\sqrt{25-r^2}rdr\theta= 
\pi \int_{0}^{5}\sqrt{25-r^2}rdr=\frac{125\pi}{3}
$$